# Date._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(NSDate?) crash in Swift 3

Tags: date, swift3, nsdate

I have following function in a swift file. I am calling this from Obj C file with NSDate in place of startDate. And quite often, not every time, my app crashes with

> Date._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(NSDate?)

How can I fix this?

```
func trackMeetingEnded(_ name: String, startDate: Date, backgroundTime: TimeInterval) {}
```

Stack trace

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftFoundation.dylib       0x102061e98 static Date._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(NSDate?) -> Date + 72
1  Acid                           0x10017ece4 @objc static ClusteredMixpanel.trackMeetingEnded(String, startDate : Date, backgroundTime : Double) -> () (MixpanelMeeting.swift)
2  Acid                           0x10073e1bc __56-[MeetingLifeCycleViewController stateInitialization]_block_invoke.221 (MeetingLifeCycleViewController.m:267)
3  Acid                           0x1001ee5c4 partial apply for thunk (StateMachine.swift)
4  Acid                           0x1001ea70c specialized State.willLeaveState(State) -> () (StateMachine.swift:238)
5  Acid                           0x1001ead90 specialized StateMachine.transitionToState(State) -> Bool (StateMachine.swift)
6  Acid                           0x1001e1f18 @objc StateMachine.transitionToState(State) -> Bool (StateMachine.swift)
7  Acid                           0x10073ace0 -[MeetingLifeCycleViewController dismissCall] (MeetingLifeCycleViewController.m:538)
8  Acid                           0x10086d648 -[InMeetingViewController hangup] (InMeetingViewController.m:531)
```

`enter code here`

I believe NSDate to Date conversion is done by OS in this case. The issue is seen only after migration to Swift 3. Are there any known issues around this? I could not find anything online :(

Comment: Paste your function or code

Answer (score 21):

This answer is meant for those that face this issue with Core Data and Swift:

In a Core Data `NSManagedObject`, you have to be careful when representing types marked as non-optional in your data model in Swift.

Core Data objects are dynamic in nature and values in memory are fulfilled dynamically at runtime by design. This isn't compatible with Swift's concept of truly non-optional types unless you define a default value in your data model.

Note that the auto generated class by default always resorts to an optional even if the attribute is marked as non-optional in the data model. **To properly support non-optionals, you have to define a default value in the model**.

You may think this is a mistake in Apple's part, but it isn't. A Core Data object can be deleted and you can still have a reference to it somewhere in the code (see the `isDeleted` property), therefore things that are marked as non-optional can be gone at runtime since Core Data can never fulfill its dynamic expectation.

While `String` and `Int`, for example, will "unconditionally bridge" to "" and `0` when `nil`, `Date` will crash as seen in this question.

Note that this isn't the case if you mark it as `NSDate` (it will return nil even if marked as non-optional), but this is not meant to be a workaround and is an implementation detail.

Test case:

Assuming your data model has `date1`, and `date2`, both non-optional and without default values.

```
@NSManaged public var date1: Date?
@NSManaged public var date2: Date
```

```
let myObject = ... 
// Assuming your object is valid, inserted, and the context is saved              
managedObjectContext.delete(myObject)
try managedObjectContext.save()
// This will be nil
NSLog("\(myObject.date1)")
// This will crash
NSLog("\(myObject.date2)")
```

In conclusion, you can use non-optional types without default values in Core Data, just be careful, as at runtime they may disappear and crash in the case of Date, or be represented in something you don't expect as in the case of String and Int.

Note: you should still make use of the ability to mark an attribute as non-optional, even if in Swift it is represented as an optional. This is taken into account into Core Data's validation code for objects.

Comment: I am using a non-optional with a default value, and I still rarely get this crash when processing persistent history.

Comment: You don't specify which type it is. Generally, it isn't a good idea to use non-optionals with NSManagedObject's in Swift, even if you set a default value. There are many reasons why Core Data not be able to fulfill that property.

Comment: what are the "many" other reasons where this could fail?

Comment: The object is deleted, the underlying data store is gone, etc. You'll have to look up the documented or implementation details of how Core Data moves your data store into memory and uses default values if necessary.

Comment: I don’t think this answer is correct. Setting a default value in the model lets you save an object with a required attribute that’s not specified. And you can you can access the attribute after creating the object. But if the attribute becomes nil because it gets set to nil or because of deletion it will still crash when bridging to Swift.

Answer (score 14):

You probably need to double check that the `NSDate` coming from Objective-C is actually non-`nil`, since there's nothing that's actively enforcing that on the Obj-C side the way there is on the Swift side.

I wound up converting as many `Date`s to `Date?`s as I could find being called from Obj-C, then doing a whole lot of `guard let` checks.

You can also throw in an `assertionFailure` to yell at you when you're in development about where those `nil` dates you're not expecting are coming from. For example:

```
guard let date = passedInDate else {
    assertionFailure("Turns out the passed-in date was nil!")
    return 
}
```

Then take a look at your stack trace when that gets hit to see if you can get a better grip on why you're getting an unexpected `nil` value there.

Update: [Here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Date.swift#L260)'s where the crash is occurring in the Swift source code.

Comment: I had to make startDate as optional. Turns out nil was being passed.

Answer (score 3):

Extending [Marc Etcheverry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258215/2932640) answer for swift & coreData + multithreading environment.

Be aware that `NSFetchRequest` has a property called `returnsObjectsAsFaults` that is `true` by default ([apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506756-returnsobjectsasfaults)) this means that you will retrieve your `NSManagedObject` but its properties won't actually be filled until you access them, so if by any chance a different thread removed that instance from core data by the moment you're accessing the property (Date in this case `Date._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC`) it can be nil and your non-optional `Date` can crash the app.

Picture this scenario:

```
Thread 1 

 - [step 1] let values = Fetch [NSManagedObject]

 - [step 3] let values[0].someDate // here app will crash
```

Since `returnsObjectsAsFaults` is `true` [by default] `someDate` property was not fetched until you tried to access it.

```
Thread 2 

 - [step 2] update coreData - hence removing objects fetched on Thread 1 - step 1
```

**Solution**: if you do need all your properties from the beginning from your `NSManagedObject` make sure to set on your fetchRequest:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: "someEntity")
...
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still trying to figure out to solve this problem:

1. Make sure that in Swift, the value you are assigning is optional;
2. Make sure that **the property in the ObjC class, is marked as `nullable`**.

i.e.

ObjC

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Item : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, nullable) NSDate *imageURL;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and in Swift:

```
var imageURL: Date? = itme.imageURL
```

This will solve the problem.
If you don't mark the property as nullable in ObjC, Swift will assume this cannot be nil, although you correctly declared it as `Date?`. This will result in the crash mentioned in the title.
Once you add `nullable` in ObjC, the crash will be resolved.