# Circumvent ObjC to Swift bridge with KVC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

Recently ran into a crash in our app:

```
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001c5c8986c
static URLRequest._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC(_:)
```

It's coming from a webView decide policy where we access the request property:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
   let req = navigationAction.sourceFrame.request
}
```

I believe the problem is on this line in swift lib:
https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/URLRequest.swift#L298

There are no guards in place here, and it seems like on the objc side it's possible that the request is nil.

My question is regarding how to get around the objc to swift bridge. Would KVC avoid that?

```
if let req = navigationAction.sourceFrame.value(forKey: "request") as NSURLRequest {
    //do stuff
}
```

If there's no way to circumvent the objc to swift bridge it's a crash we will have to live with? It is not happening too frequently, but enough that we would love to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right assuming that `request` is `nil`, when the error occurs. A similar problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44031789/1987726).
Since `URLRequest.swift`, as defined in `apple/swift-corelibs-foundation` that your cited will definitively crash if request is `nil`, one cannot use it in this situation.
One alternative is definitively to use KVO, since `func value(forKey key: String) -> Any?`
can return `nil` values, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-value).
However, you can only use it, if the object, in which the function is called, adopted the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol, which is ensured if the object is a subclass of `NSObject`, which I cannot tell from your code fragment.
But since you suggested this already in your question, did you try it?

Comment: Thanks! The class in question is WKNavigationAction, which subclasses NSObject. I tried it and it works. I do receive an NSMutableURLRequest, which I'm guessing is how it's stored in objc but not publicly exposed as mutable. Ultimately I was trying to confirm that this will successfully circumvent objc->swift bridge which it seems like it will.

Comment: Maybe you can accept my answer, even if the solution was your idea, just to close the question?

Comment: I'll accept it even though I haven't confirmed yet. I will be able to confirm once we release and update and see if it stops the crash :)